# Eclipse CDT (Windows/Cygwin) Ignoring Breakpoints - answers to other posts have not helped

Tags: debugging, gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

Running the latest stable version of Eclipse CDT on an up-to-date Windows 10 x64. I started off with the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and then installed CDT plugin minus preview/beta/experimental features - it is my only plugin; I'm able to debug Java projects just fine, but when it comes to using gdb in C it does not stop on breakpoints at all; the debugger works perfectly fine otherwise. I can step through program, examine variables, see assembly output. I can even see the breakpoints correlating to the assembly.

I've gone through several posts on StackOverflow and various forums and none of them have helped me. In light of their suggestions, here is my current situation:

- I do NOT have the "Skip All Breakpoints" button accidentally enabled. (I've also toggled it on-off during program execution, does not help.)
- I AM in the Debug perspective
- Running Eclipse as Administrator does NOT fix the problem
- Disabling "stop on startup" does NOT fix the problem
- I am using the default debug configuration, so there is no optimization and maximum debugging information (currently using -O0 -g3 flags)
- Passing the -ggdb3 flag does not help
- I've tried various combinations of cleaning/rebuilding project/clearing breakpoints/restarting Eclipse
- I've tried creating new projects and copying and creating new source files and copying and pasting the contents of the original sources into the new ones - new project does not fix anything
- The breakpoints I am testing are in guaranteed-to-hit-places in main (eg. a simple "Hello World" program with only multiple printf statements), so there is no issue regarding loading libraries or other source files
- Run -> Breakpoint Types is currently set to C/C++ Breakpoints

I hope someone is able to assist!

Comment: Saying what does not help does not help without saying how the problem can be reproduced. Avoid doing trial and error.

Comment: I have a refresh installation - I do not know what causes the problem to begin with, especially since it affects one language but not the other. In order to avoid wasting any time, I've listed points covered in the 30 or so topics I've read on this issue that solved the problem for some people but not for me, that way they aren't covered twice.

Comment: Debugging Java and C/C++ are different things, even if they share some of the same UI. Please edit your question and say exactly how to reproduce the issue, tell which documentation/tutorial you followed and delete everything else .